# Keep corresponding rownames when aggregating dataframe rows by column element

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a dataframe `Df` with some rows that have repeated elements on `column A and B`

```
> Df
       A      B   C   D   E   F   G
1    Aiz    Geo   1   0   0   0   0   
2   Aren   Meso   0   1   1   0   1   
3   Aren   Meso   0   0   1   0   1   
4  Atxos    Geo   1   0   0   0   1   
5  Atxos    Geo   0   0   1   1   0   
6    Cab   Cast   1   0   0   1   0   
7    Cab   Cast   1   0   1   1   1    
8    Cab   Call   1   0   0   1   1
```

I want to aggregate the rows in such a way that it considers the pair of elements in both column A and B, and sums those that are repeated. In short, this is what I would like to obtain:

```
> agg_Df
       A      B   C   D   E   F   G
1    Aiz    Geo   1   0   0   0   0   
2   Aren   Meso   0   1   2   0   2    
3  Atxos    Geo   1   0   1   1   1   
4    Cab   Cast   2   0   1   2   1    
5    Cab   Call   1   0   0   1   1
```

I know I can use the `aggregate` function to aggregate by one of the columns:

```
aggregate(.~A,data=Df,FUN=sum)
```

But this only works if there is only one column with characters, the one used for the aggregation.
As you can see on `Df` above for `row 6:8`, even if the elements on column `A` are the same for the three, it's not the same for column `B` where `row 8` has a different element. Therefore the values of this row can't be summed into the other two rows. So it's imperative I aggregate taking into account the results of the two columns. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just group and summarise across the columns C to G:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(A,B) %>% 
  summarise(across(c(C:G), sum))
```

Output:

```
  A     B         C     D     E     F     G
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Aiz   Geo       1     0     0     0     0
2 Aren  Meso      0     1     2     0     2
3 Atxos Geo       1     0     1     1     1
4 Cab   Call      1     0     0     1     1
5 Cab   Cast      2     0     1     2     1
```

Comment: this worked perfectly. Thank you very much!! Just one doubt. Just one extra doubt. I have rownames, which are to be used as the actual tags for plotting and further analysis. This approach leads the results to loose the associated rownames, which I need. Any suggestion on how to retain them?

Comment: `dplyr` will never preserve rownames.  Rownames make sense
for matrices, but not for data frames. Make them an explicit variable. As stated here: <https://groups.google.com/g/manipulatr/c/mClU7eQLRzw>. Use: `tibble::rownames_to_column(df, "row_name")`

Answer (score 0):

The below should do the trick:

```
library (tidyverse)

agg_Df <- cbind(A, B, C, D, E, F, G) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  group_by(A, B, .drop = F) %>%
  mutate(across(C:G, as.numeric)) %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), 
                ~sum(.))) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: I think I am missing something for this code to work. You have `cbind` to bind the columns, but I don't have them as vectors. I tried to call them from the `Df` itself but to no avail. Should I generate the vectors first? Cause this would be a bit cumbersome since my data has quite a long list of columns.